# Translation Commutation with Function of Position Operator in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, commutator

I'm trying to show the following:

$\displaystyle{\left[e^{-i\hat{p}\epsilon/\hbar}, f(\hat{x})\right]} = 0.$

I'm aware that the left operator is the positional translation operator, but I'm not sure how to prove this statement. I've tried taking the series expansions of both of them and looking for rules of the commutation relations, but I've not got anywhere. Can anybody advise me on how to solve this?

Comment: I see now that you change your question quite a bit. Still the formulae I wrote would tell you why that commutator is zero.

Comment: Please do not heavily edit questions so that current answers become confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Start by noticing that, using [Baker-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula,
$$e^{-i\hat{p}\alpha/\hbar}\hat{x}e^{i\hat{p}\alpha/\hbar} = \hat{x}-\alpha$$
and from this $$e^{-i\hat{p}\alpha/\hbar}f(\hat{x})e^{i\hat{p}\alpha/\hbar} = f(\hat{x}-\alpha)$$
Now write the commutation relations explicitly, and see that you can make them resemble this formula.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that you want to compute the commutation between the translation operator by $a$, $T_a$ with the operator multiplication by a function (say $g$) $M_g$. These operators are defined in the following way:

\begin{align}
(T_a f) (x)& = f(x-a) \\
(M_g)(x)&= g(x)f(x)
\end{align}

Hence $(T_a M_g f) (x)= g(x-a) f(x-a)$ and $ (M_g T_a f)(x) = g(x)f(x-a)$. This means that

$$
[M_g, T_a] = M_{g'} T_a
$$

Where $g'(x) = g(x)-g(x-a)$. In the particular case $g(x)=x$ (which may be what you are interested in), you get $g'(x) =a$ and the commutator is simply $aT_a$.